# R: lapply leads to different result in step function

Tags: r

In swiss data I try to do stepwise linear regression for different range of Agriculture, so I tried:

```
data <- swiss
splits <- split(data, cut(data$Agriculture, breaks=c(0, 50, Inf), right=FALSE))

select <- function(x) {
  null <- lm(Fertility~1, data=splits[[x]])
  full <- lm(Fertility~., data=splits[[x]])
  step(null, scope=list(lower=null, upper=full, direction='forward'))
}
select(2)
```

this would work but the following doesn't:

```
null_list <- lapply(splits, function(x) {lm(Fertility~1, data=x)})
full_list <- lapply(splits, function(x) {lm(Fertility~., data=x)})

select <- function(x) {
  null <- null_list[[x]]
  full <- full_list[[x]]
  step(null, scope=list(lower=null, upper=full, direction='forward'))   
}
select(2)
```

The second version throws error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Fertility' not found
```

But when I check

```
lm(Fertility~1, data=splits[[2]])
null_list[[2]]
```

and

```
lm(Fertility~., data=splits[[2]])
full_list[[2]]
```

They both look the same. What makes the difference? Any stupid mistakes made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you look at the calls for the two versions, you'll see they are not exactly the same

```
lm(Fertility~1, data=splits[[2]])$call
# lm(formula = Fertility ~ 1, data = splits[[2]])

null_list[[2]]$call
# lm(formula = Fertility ~ 1, data = x)
```

Notice how the `data=` argument is different for each. The former still points to a valid global variable, the latter points to `x` which does not exist any more. The `step()` function tries to evaluate the formula in a context from where it was called. And in that context `x` is your loop counter. If you changed the `select()` function to

```
select <- function(z) {
  null <- null_list[[z]]
  full <- full_list[[z]]
  step(null, scope=list(lower=null, upper=full, direction='forward'))   
}
select(2)
```

You'd get a different error

```
Error in is.data.frame(data) : object 'x' not found
```

which basically means that `step()` is having trouble getting back to the variable that contains the data that can be used to re-fit a model adding or subtracting a covariate.

One work around would be to embed the data in the `lm()` call itself. You can do that with

```
null_list <- lapply(splits, function(x) {do.call("lm", list(Fertility~1, data=x))})
full_list <- lapply(splits, function(x) {do.call("lm", list(Fertility~., data=x))})
```

But you'll see this results in a "messy-looking" call but the the results should be the same.

This is unfortunately a side-effect of non-standard evaluation. It would be nice if `step()` looked for the data in the `$model` property of the full model, but I believe this doesn't match up when you have NA values so R has no choice but to try to re-evaluate the `data=` parameter in some context.